# Creating multiple contact forms on my site

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create two contact forms on my website using Node.js, and each one requires its own package.json file. I've tried installing the necessary packages so that a package.json file will be created for the second time, but it's not working. It seems I cannot create two in one folder.

Does anyone know what I can do to create a new package.json file for this new contact form in the same folder?

Thank you!

Comment: "each one requires its own package.json file" — Err. That is not normal. Are you trying to run two completely separate Node.js applications?

Comment: Why do you need two package.json? that's not possible. In that file you describe dependencies and scripts (and more stuff) do you want two set of dependencies? that sounds like two different applications

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Quentin  From what I understand, I would like to run two different Node applications. I am using Nodemailer to send information from a contact form to my email, and now I would like to do the same with another contact form in the same project. I have a Request,js file, a Server.js file, and a package.json file. I would like to also do what I am doing with a Payment.js file, a Server2.js file, and a package.json file. How can I use the same package.json file for Nodemailer (ie how can I run 2 Node applications in the same project?)

Comment: @PabloAragon From what I understand, I would like to run two different Node applications. I am using Nodemailer to send information from a contact form to my email, and now I would like to do the same with another contact form in the same project. I have a Request,js file, a Server.js file, and a package.json file. I would like to also do what I am doing with a Payment.js file, a Server2.js file, and a package.json file. How can I use the same package.json file for Nodemailer (ie how can I run 2 Node applications in the same project?)

Comment: Nodemailer is a module, not an application. You use it by writing you own application which imports it and then does stuff with it. I don’t see any reason to complicate matters by writing two almost identical applications instead of a single one. That you’re considering otherwise suggests you should be working through an introductory Node.js tutorial rather than trying to solve a specific problem.

Comment: @Quentin My apologies for using the wrong terminology. I just don't know how I can have two contact forms in one application. I am using this tutorial but don't know how to use a package.json file for two different contact forms. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30VeUWxZjS8&list=LLI20_tc6smebe6CRXpOiHzQ&index=9

Comment: Like I said, you should be looking at introductory tutorials rather than how-to-solve-narrow-problem guides.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have 2 different applications within one single project, you should have to entry points (I think it would be Server.js and Server2.js).

Then you want to run two different instances of the same project: one starting Server.js and another one starting Server2.js. You can do it with two different scripts in the package.json. Example:

```
// package.json
...
"scripts": {
  "start:1": "node Server.js",
  "start:2": "node Server2.js"
}
...
```

And you can start them with:

```
$ npm run start:1
$ npm run start:2
```

Notice that if both applications run on the same machine, they should run on different ports.